# New SDK project missing "Start External Command" in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Old .NET Projects have an option under debug that allows "Start External Command" as shown in this figure

[image]

When I create a new project using the new SDK style, I can't see the same option (as the figure below). **Is there a way to get it back?**

- Both pictures were taken from the same VS (so it is not version specific)
- A workaround that I found is running the program normally and attach to it but it is not convenient.

[image]

Comment: After my testing, in both versions 19 and 22. I saw the same settings as the first picture on the `Winform` of the `framework`, and the second picture in the `core`. Do you want to change the version to the `framework`? What kind of environment are you referring to in the `old net`?

Comment: Good question, they broke quite a few things with the refactoring of these settings.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT, Both pictures are for .NET Framework 4.8 class library. For VS 2022, I created an .NET Core 3.1 project, then changed csproj to .net48

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the Launch Profiles window, you have a "new profile" icon in the top left hand corner. If you click that, a menu opens and lets you choose either a Project or an Executable File. If you choose the later, you get the option back for which you were looking.

[image: The "new start profile" menu]

Comment: For the sake of completeness, this window is now called `Launch Profiles` and can still be reached from the Project Properties --> Debug.

Answer (score 0):

I have no Idea why but, in creating my own template, I experienced the same missing "Start Action".

I couldn't understand, since I was using the same SDK and versions, why one Project Solution showed the "Start Action" and the other didn't. Once I saved the solution and closed the multiple sessions I had open, and then reopened the solution, the "Start Action" appeared.