# How to specify multiple debugging commands in visual studio 2022 for c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-code

In vs you can edit your debugging command in `Configuration Properties -> Debugging`. But when you have multiple debugging scenarios to review, it is very cumbersome to be constantly adjusting the `Command Arguments` entry.

I was hoping one can do similar to a cmake project in vscode, where you can edit a `launch.json` file that will have multiple debugging commands ready for you to select and run, each with their own arguments, for example:

```
{
    "name": "(Windows) Launch",
    "type": "cppvsdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
    "environment": [],
    "console": "externalTerminal"
},
```

Note: Answers to VS2019 are also welcomed.

Comment: It's a bit of a sledgehammer to crack a walnut but you could create a different configuration for each of your debug commands.

Comment: Are you talking about Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? And which version do you use? VS2022 has exactly this as new feature.

Comment: @PMF Does it? Cool.

Comment: I am asking about visual studio, and bringing vscode as a reference.
I use VS2019 and VS2022.
Awesome, where?

Comment: @PaulSanders I've added an answer about this new feature.

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem? If the reply is helpful, you could click '✔' to mark it as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

(See also [New SDK project missing "Start External Command" in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70673777/new-sdk-project-missing-start-external-command-in-visual-studio/70686187#70686187). )

There's a new "launch profiles" dialog. You find it either by clicking there:
[image: either here]
or on the small down arrow next to the "Start project" element in the toolbar (and then choose the last element in the menu):
[image]

In this new dialog, you can create an arbitrary number of startup configurations with different startup parameters. Very helpful for debugging console applications. To add a new configuration, click the "New project configuration" icon in the top left corner. Each entry can have different command line options. To choose which one to start, tick it in the drop-down menu of the start button.

Comment: thanks, but this is not working for c/c++ projects, only for c# projects.

Comment: I haven't debugged C++ apps in a while, but this sounds like a missing feature then. No idea why C# and C++ should act differently here.