Visual Studio 2022: where is: Debug > Start Action > Start external program
I'm following this tutorial instructing me to set this configuration:

Click on Debug tab, and in Start Action section choose Start external program. To the corresponding textbox, set the path to the kd_app.exe / cp.exe file in your KitchenDraw / InSitu installation folder.


But on my Visual Studio 2022 I cannot find such a config:

Question

Where is the config for this: Debug > Start Action > Start external program?
Is it possible to switch to a classical properties dialog just like the one inside the tutorial?


Can someone tell me what version of Visual Studio is that tutorial using?

Actually, there is a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70686187/3405291

Starting in Visual Studio 2022, the feature "Open debug launch profiles UI " was released. Looks like the version of Visual Studio that tutorial using is prior to 2022.(e.g:VS2019)

This question is similar to: New SDK project missing "Start External Command" in visual studio. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ChristophRackwitz Right. Just to clarify, I had to make sure to delete the previous outdated profile. Without deleting the previous profile, the new profile was not taking effect for me. So, I posted a new answer for completeness.

what happens if you don't delete the existing profile? -- you can post answers on questions you didn't ask, such as that older question linked above.

@ChristophRackwitz You're right. I found that question after asking a new one here :) Next time, I should search more before asking =D

@ChristophRackwitz Also, I can delete this question and post my answer to that previous question.

The Open debug launch profiles UI link has to be clicked:

Then, A new Executable profile has to be created to be able to access the configuration for Path to the executable to run. Make sure to delete the previous outdated profile.


